# I can't understand how .gitignore works

Tags: git, gitignore

In the root of my (versioned) project I create a folder with a .sh file inside and a README file. Then with the command `git status` the output (correctly) was that I've to `git add` the new files.

I don't `git add` the files but I added them to `.gitignore` file.
After that, with `git status` the output was that I have to `git add` the modified `.gitignore`.

Then I print `git add .` and `git commit` commands.
Now my two initial files are not present and I can't understand why.

With adding files in `.gitignore` I thought that the files were present but the changes were not tracked but not that they disappeared.

Did I get it wrong or did I make some mistakes?
What happened to those files?

Comment: did the files disappear from `git status` or from the filesystem (e.g. `ls` or `dir`)?
adding a file to `.gitignore` causes git to not care about them, but they should still be present in the filesystem.

Comment: files disappeared in the filesystem

Comment: You must have done something else as well, as nothing you lists here would delete any files. Have you checked your Trash Can/Recycle Bin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+what+is

Comment: Thanks, ok so you confirmed to me that gitignore works as I intended and it's the most important thing. I did some tests and now it seems to work as expected. But I checked now and those file aren't in trash, I'm sure I created those files in the same commit because they were marked in the .gitignore so I didn't confuse commit. Anyway I must have done something else wrong.